# Finding the Row Number of two numbers in a Pascal's Triangle

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

This should be a combinatorics question:

> Two successive numbers in the $n$th row of Pascal's Triangle are 455 and 1365. Find $n$.

If I let $n$ be the row number, i.e. row number starts from 0, 1, 2 ...., and I let $k$ be the loccation of 455. I get the relationship $n=4k+3$.

I know that I could continue in some way since I know what the numbers are. Can anyone help me?

Comment: It is helpful to include any work you have already done so others do not have to repeat it. For example, you found $n=4k+3$ using something like $$\binom{n}{k+1}\big/\binom{n}k=\frac{n-k}{k+1}=1365/455=3$$

Comment: Trial and error works very quickly.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Yes definitely, sorry. I've forgotten to do that.

Comment: @lulu Yes that definitely would work. But I'd like to try find a way to derive it.

Comment: $455=5\cdot7\cdot13$  so it appears that $13$ is the largest prime factor of $n!$.  Since $n\equiv3\pmod4$, we try $n=15,\ k=3$ which works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{\binom{n}{i}}{\binom{n}{i+1}} = \frac{i+1}{n-i}$.

We therefore have $\frac{i+1}{n-i} = \frac{455}{1365} = \frac{1}{3}$ or $n-i = 3(i+1)$ or $i=\frac{n-3}{4}$, this imples $n$ is of the form $4k+3$ so the expression is $\binom{4k+3}{k}$.

Trying with $k=0$ gives $1$ , with $k=1$ gives $7$, with $k=2$ gives $55$ and $k=3$ gives the required answer of $455$ (the fact that the next value is correct is given by the ratio).

Comment: The process is accelerated by knowing that since $13 \mid 455$, $n\ge 13$ and thus $k>2$.